# What does this mean in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

for (String key : studentGrades.keySet()) && (String key : studentAverages.keySet()){

//Where is the error?
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token "&&", for
expected
- Duplicate local variable key

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Assuming that is Java that is not valid, you can't use && like that. Looks like you need two loops.